# Перетаскивание блока по экрану, происходит залипание и не срабатывает onmouseup

Tags: javascript

```js
var deltaX;
var deltaY;
var move = document.getElementById("move");

function getMouse(e) {
  move.style.left = (e.pageX - deltaX) + "px";
  move.style.top = (e.pageY - deltaY) + "px";
  console.log()
  if (move.offsetLeft >= 700) {
    move.style.left = 699 + "px";
  }
  if (move.offsetTop <= 200 || move.offsetTop >= 202) {
    move.style.top = 201 + "px";
  }
}

move.onmousedown = function(e) {
  deltaX = e.pageX - move.offsetLeft;
  deltaY = e.pageY - move.offsetTop;
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', getMouse);
}

move.onmouseup = function(e) {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', getMouse);
}
```

```css
#divStyle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

#move {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="divStyle">
  <div id="move"></div>
</div>
```

Перетаскивайте зеленый блок, иногда происходит залипание, не срабатывает move.onmouseup. Подскажите пожалуйста почему?

Comment: Потому что во время перетаскивания вы покидаете страницу где находиться зеленый блок. Можно сделать проверку если указатель вышел за пределы контейнера, то вызвать метод `onmousedown`. И тогда залипания не будет.

Comment: А если просто onmouseup на родитель повесить? Я сделал вроде норма, не знаю правильно или нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так.

```js
var deltaX;
var deltaY;
var move = document.getElementById("move");
var divStyle = document.getElementById("divStyle");
var divLeft = divStyle.offsetLeft;
var divRight = divStyle.offsetLeft + divStyle.offsetWidth;

function getMouse(e) {
  move.style.left = (e.pageX - deltaX) + "px";
  move.style.top = (e.pageY - deltaY) + "px";
  if (move.offsetLeft >= 700) {
    move.style.left = 699 + "px";
  }
  if (move.offsetTop <= 200 || move.offsetTop >= 202) {
    move.style.top = 201 + "px";
  }
  if (getMousePosition(e).x < divLeft || getMousePosition(e).x > divRight) {
    console.log(getMousePosition(e).x < divLeft || getMousePosition(e).x > divRight)
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', getMouse);
  }

}

function getMousePosition(e) {
  var x = y = 0;

  if (!e) {
    var e = window.event;
  }

  if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
  } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
    x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
}

move.onmousedown = function(e) {
  deltaX = e.pageX - move.offsetLeft;
  deltaY = e.pageY - move.offsetTop;
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', getMouse);
}

move.onmouseup = function(e) {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', getMouse);
}
```

```css
#divStyle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

#move {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="divStyle">
  <div id="move"></div>
</div>
```